# BehaviorSubject isn't considered to be empty

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I create `BehaviorSubject` like this:

```
private val viewStateSubject: BehaviorSubject<StateT> = BehaviorSubject.create()
```

Later on I subsribe on it the following way:

```
viewStateDisposable = viewStateSubject
            .defaultIfEmpty(createInitialState())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(view::switchToState)
```

But it never emits any item. But if I create subject with default value, like this:

```
private val viewStateSubject: BehaviorSubject<StateT> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(createInitialState())
```

And remove `defaultIfEmpty` from subscription, then it emits the default value. AFAIK it is because by default BehaviorSubject is initialized with `EMPTY` value, so it is never actually empty.

Unfortunately I can't use the second solution. How can I switch to default value then? Notice that I want to be able to subscribe and unsubscribe to the same subject multiple times and receive default value only on the first subscription. It means that I can't immediately pass the default value into the subject or `skip` first.

Comment: defaultIfEmpty requires the source to complete without items. Why can't you use the second solution? You can use startWith or simply push the initial value into the BehaviorSubject.

Comment: As you can see initial value is provided via a method. It is non final method and I initiate subject in constructor. Is I use the startWith or push then this value will be pushed on eah attempt to subsribe, while I need it only on the very first one.

Comment: So you have multiple consumers and you want only one of them receive the initial value?

Comment: No. I need an item, which will be emitted for anyone unless I publish the new item. At the same time I can't use createDefault.

Comment: Do you have access to `viewStateSubject`? If yes, just call `viewStateSubject.onNext(initialObject)` as early as possible. Also not sure why you can't have `createDefault`, but it is the more appropriate way. Who is owning that creation code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AFAIK it is because by default `BehaviorSubject` is initialized with `EMPTY` value, so it is never actually empty.

No, `BehaviorSubject` does not emit anything if created without a default item. This is why it never emits anything in your case.

---

**Regarding `defaultIfEmpty()`**:

[`defaultIfEmpty()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#defaultIfEmpty-T-) only takes affect once the `Observable` completes without emitting any items. So, it will only work if you call [`onCompleted()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observer.html#onCompleted--) on your `viewStateSubject` once you are done emitting items.

---

> Notice that I want to be able to subscribe and unsubscribe to the same subject multiple times and receive default value only on the first subscription.

I don't think either `BehaviorSubject.create()` with default item or `defaultIfEmpty()` can serve this purpose for you.

`BehaviorSubject.create()` with default item:
This will always emit that default value irrespective of whether its first subscription or not as long as there are no items emitted explicitly.

`defaultIfEmpty()`: As noted earlier this will only take affect if `BehaviorSubject` is completed without emitting any item.

---

**EDIT:** After clarification in the comments:

You can simply emit your default item first. Every new subscriber will receive that item unless any other item is emitted.

From the [doc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html):

> Subject that emits the most recent item it has observed and all subsequent observed items to each subscribed Observer.

```
viewStateSubject.onNext(createInitialState());
viewStateDisposable = viewStateSubject
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(view::switchToState)
```

Comment: Perhaps I described my needs wrong. I need an item, which is going to be published by subject for any consumer until I publish another item. So, exactly what createDefault does, but without createDefault usage.

Comment: I need the universal subscription code, which can be called multiple times. IN the example from updated answer if I run this code first for the first time then result is expectable. But if I then emit new item into subject and run the same code for another subscriber - it'll get the default item instead of the last emitted.

Comment: @Lingviston You should only call `viewStateSubject.onNext(createInitialState())` once in the beginning.

Comment: That's clear. Any way to do it in reactive way? Without adding flags or anything similar.

Comment: The reactive way was `BehaviorSubject.createDefault()`. Apart from that I'm not sure if there is a way.